# ADFS 3.0 Single Sign Out not working

Tags: adfs2.0, adfs3.0, adfs2.1

i am using ADFS 3.0 as sts for two asp.net apps, when i signed in to app 1 it will sign in to both app1 and app2, means app2 wont ask for credentials, but when i click signout from app1 it will signs out only from that app. and in app2 user remains signed in, what is issue? how to sign out form both the apps when signed out from any one app?

Answer (score 1):

What do you have your sign out URL set to?
On ADFS 3.0 it should be

```
https://fs.rrdsb.com/adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon.aspx
```

That will bring you to a page that gives you the option to sign out of the one app or all the signed in apps.